# Runtime error 13 / Type Mismatch

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Just spent 2 hours trying to make this simple code work. The macro selects and then deletes specified columns. Then sets ColumnWidth for Col T = 50.

Col T is the identifier **before** the other columns are deleted and remaining cols shift left.

Two questions:

1. Given that code executes line-by-line, shouldn't the Col T specified for width re-size actually be a different column, i.e. the new col letter after cols are deleted and remaining cols are shifted left?
2. How can I use the info in the editor "view window" (see below) to debug this code?

   ```
   Watch :Columns("A:G,I:I,K:S,U:Z") : <Out of context> : Variant/Empty : Del_sel_cols_set_col_width50.del_selected_cols_resizeColT_width50

   Watch :Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50 : <Out of context> : Variant/Empty : Del_sel_cols_set_col_width50.del_selected_cols_resizeColT_width50
   ```

My code...

```
Sub del_selected_cols_resizeColT_width50()

    Columns("A:G,I:I,K:S,U:Z").Delete

    Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the column reference to a range reference and specify EntireColumn.

Yes, column T becomes column C after the deletions.

```
'either resize column T here
Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50

Range("A:G,I:I,K:S,U:Z").EntireColumn.Delete

'or resize the new column C (formerly T) here
Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 50
```

Comment: Perfect solution. "Jeeped"'s inclusion of 2 possible solutions is especially helpful to OP in terms of enhancing my understanding of the code sequence execution. The commented out remarks also very informative, esp. for noob coder.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Columns("U:Z").Delete
Columns("K:S").Delete
Columns("I").Delete
Columns("A:G").Delete
Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50
```

Comment: All code for ".Delete" run fine. The